# How do I make a string outlive a closure body?

Tags: rust, rust-warp

I have this code:

```
.and_then(move |key: Option<String>| async {
    let pool = pool.clone();
    let key = key.as_ref().map(|s| &**s);

    match pool.get() {
        Ok(conn) => Ok(Session::from_key(conn, key)),
        Err(e) => {
            error!("Failed to get a db connection");
            Err(warp::reject::not_found())
        }
    }
})
.boxed()
```

Which I am adapting from [this example](https://github.com/kaj/warp-diesel-ructe-sample/blob/master/src/session.rs#L123)

But it's giving me the error

```
lifetime may not live long enough

returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`

note: closure implements `Fn`, so references to captured variables can't escape the closurerustc
session.rs(131, 19): lifetime `'1` represents this closure's body
session.rs(131, 44): return type of closure is impl core::future::future::Future
session.rs(131, 46): returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
async block may outlive the current function, but it borrows `key`, which is owned by the current function

may outlive borrowed value `key`rustc(E0373)
session.rs(131, 52): may outlive borrowed value `key`
session.rs(133, 23): `key` is borrowed here
```

I had to add the `async` keyword to the closure to avoid the  error:

```
the trait bound `std::result::Result<session::Session, warp::reject::Rejection>: core::future::future::Future` is not satisfied

the trait `core::future::future::Future` is not implemented for `std::result::Result<session::Session, warp::reject::Rejection>`

note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `futures_core::future::TryFuture` for `std::result::Result<session::Session, warp::reject::Rejection>`rustc(E0277)
session.rs(138, 10): the trait `core::future::future::Future` is not implemented for `std::result::Result<session::Session, warp::reject::Rejection>`
```

So, now, it appears the closure is returning a feature, but the closure is deallocated, so it tries to deallocate the future before it is used...any ideas on how to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

The main thing to understand about this problem is that the parameter to this closure, `key` is passed by-value, `String` is an owned string. So when this closure is running, `key` is owned in the stackframe for this closure, and when the closure returns, this stack frame and everything in it gets `drop()`ed.

`key.as_ref()` produces a value which references the `key` in this stack frame, rustc doesn't let you return something from a function which references values owned by the function as they wont exist once the function returns, this is why the lifetime is limited to the function body.

To remedy this you have 2 options:

1. Pass `key` by reference to this function `key: Option<&str>`, then the `Session` can be returned back up the stack until where the owned string was borrowed.
2. Create the `Session` using the owned string, then the String is owned by the Session and can be passed around by value (moved) without any lifetime restrictions.